# Index of a subgroup, H, of G and the largest normal subgroup of G contained in H.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a hard time following this proof on pg. 145 of Dummit and Foote:

We are given a simple group of order 60. To show that there exist no proper subgroup $H$ of index less than $5$ the theorem concerning the kernel of the action of $G$ on the  set of left cosets of $H$ is used. The theorem states that the kernel of the permutation representation is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. Now if $|G:H| < 5$ we can somehow conclude from this theorem that that there exist a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ contained in $H$.

I am really lost as to how to relate the index of $H$ to this theorem...
Any help is appreciated!

Also, I am not asking how to prove this in the case that the order of the group is $60$, I am looking for a more general explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ acts on $G/H$, you get a permutation representation
$$
\varphi : G \to S_n
$$
where $n=[G:H]$.

Now, $K:= \ker(\varphi) \subset H$ (check this). In particular $K\neq G$. Also, $|K|\mid |G|$. Furthermore,
$$
[G:K] \mid n!
$$
From this you can conclude that $K\neq \{e\}$, which now violates the fact that $G$ is simple.